# How to correctly determine volume in dB from getByteFrequencyData

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I know that `getByteFrequencyData` returns the volume in dB of each frequency band. How do I determine the **total** volume in dB of the signal to show in a VU meter?

Most of the time I see code that simply adds the volume of each frequency band and then devides the sum by the number of bands but this for sure is not correct. It would mean that EVERY frequency band would need to be at 6 dB for the whole signal to have 6 dB. That, of course, is not the case.

My questions:

1. How can I determine the total volume of the signal **correctly**?
2. If `minDecibels`is set to -96 and `maxDecibels` to 0, I assume that a value of 0 translates to -96 dB and a value of 255 to 0 db. But: What would a value of 128 mean? -48 dB?

Answer (score 4):

1. I think this depends on what you mean by "volume".  If it's the energy of the signal, then you can just take the average of the output from `getFloatFrequencyData`, but the average should not average the dB values.  You need to convert to linear before doing the average.  This is expensive; you could just take the time domain data and compute the average sum of squares and get the same answer (almost).
2. Yes, the FFT data is converted to dB and then linearly mapped between the min and max values.  See https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#widl-AnalyserNode-getByteFrequencyData-void-Uint8Array-array.

Comment: Thanks for that. By "volume" I mean the same that VU meters show in professional audio software. I want to create a similar VU. The VU meter should show the level from -96 to 0 dB. How would I do that?

Comment: Google is your friend. One example I found is https://github.com/cwilso/volume-meter.  That should get you started.

Comment: So is reading. 1. The example you are linking to does not work. 2. It uses a method that is deprecated: https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#the-scriptprocessornode-interface---deprecated 3. Read my question: I know how to get the channel data. What I do not know is how to calculate the volume **in dB** properly.

Comment: The code there says it uses the RMS value to get the volume which you can convert to dB for display.  The problem with using AnalyserNode is that the timing is not necessarily consistent.  The ScriptProcessorNode timing is consistent (if you pick a large enough buffer size).

Answer (score 2):

I found @tom-hazledine's approach of `Math.max` to generate too loud of a spectrum, effectively maxing out the volume meter very quickly.

Here's another approach that simply takes the average, and it can be modified easily to adjust if still too loud:

```js
var array = new Uint8Array( buffer_size );

listenerNode.onaudioprocess = function(){

    // Get the audio data and store it in our array.
    volume_analyser.getByteFrequencyData( array );

    // Get the peak frequency value.
    var peak_frequency = array.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / array.length;

    // ...
}
```

To reduce the average even further, simply add to the length of the array (ie. `array.length + 100`)

Or for a more *proper* mathematical way to do this, but it also creates too loud of a signal, is:

```js
var array = new Uint8Array( buffer_size );

listenerNode.onaudioprocess = function(){

    // Get the audio data and store it in our array.
    volume_analyser.getByteFrequencyData( array );

    // Get the peak frequency value.
    let sum = 0
    for (const amplitude of array) {
      sum += amplitude * amplitude
    }

    const volume = Math.sqrt(sum / array.length)
}
```

This can also be adjusted by adding to the array length as described above.

Answer (score 1):

I've been wrestling with this issue too - the results from an average of the `getByteFrequencyData` output just doesn't look right.

A simplistic solution would be to return just the *peak* value from the frequency data.

```
var array = new Uint8Array( buffer_size );

listenerNode.onaudioprocess = function(){

    // Get the audio data and store it in our array.
    volume_analyser.getByteFrequencyData( array );

    // Get the peak frequency value.
    var peak_frequency = Math.max.apply( null, array );

    // ...
}
```

This produces results that *look* normal on a VU meter display.

Comment: I am not sure if that does the trick as this will only give you the volume of frequency band with the highest volume. But the "total" volume is a mixture of the volume of all frequency bands.

Comment: I does feel a little hacky, I agree. Having used this method for a while, though, it does behave like the analogue VU meters I'm used to. If we take an average then we'd only get a maximum volume if ALL frequencies were at 0dBFS. In a real world setting, if one frequency band is clipping you want to know about it!